# Linq query to Datable in C# console

Tags: c#, linq, console

```
var query = from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                where (r.Field<double?>(dataTable.Columns[0]).Equals(invoiceNo))
                select new
                        {
                            invoice = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[0]),
                            name = r.Field<string>(dataTable.Columns[1]),
                            emp_id = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[2]),
                            won = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[3]),
                            expenses = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[4]),
                        };
```

This is my linq query which reads all the data in from dataTable.

```
 I want the query to be converted again into a datatable.Is it possible?
```

Comment: The question look alright, there is no need to edit it any further.

Answer (score 5):

You can use method [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx):

```
 DataTable dt = (from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                where (r.Field<double?>(dataTable.Columns[0]).Equals(invoiceNo)))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: am not able to add CopyToDataTable to my query as u said.getting an error like this. "'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToDataTable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @user2405133: Remoeve your `Select` clause first, and do exactly the code below

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]{_dataTable.Columns["Invoice"]};

dataTable.Rows.Find(invoiceNo)
```